# Scala: Convert a vector of tuples containing a future to a future of a vector of tuples

Tags: scala, future

I'm looking for a way to convert a `Vector[(Future[TypeA], TypeB)]` to a `Future[Vector[(TypeA, TypeB)]]`.

I'm aware of the conversion of a collection of futures to a future of a collection using `Future.sequence(...)` but cannot find out a way to manage the step from the tuple with a future to a future of tuple.

So I'm looking for something that implements the desired functionality of the dummy `extractFutureFromTuple` in the following.

```
val vectorOfTuples: Vector[(Future[TypeA], TypeB)] = ...
val vectorOfFutures: Vector[Future[(TypeA, TypeB)]] = vectorOfTuples.map(_.extractFutureFromTuple)
val futureVector: Future[Vector[(TypeA, TypeB)]] = Future.sequence(vectorOfFutures)
```

Comment: `tuple => tuple._1.map(_ -> tuple._2)`

Comment: perfect, that did the trick! thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you can do this with a single call to `Future.traverse`:

```
val input: Vector[(Future[Int], Long)] = ???
val output: Future[Vector[(Int, Long)]] = Future.traverse(input) {
  case (f, v) => f.map(_ -> v)
}
```